# Make items equal heights and specify which column they are in with CSS?

Tags: css

I have 2 columns. I need to specify which column items are in, but I also need them to have the same height.

So currently I have this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyGewd

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cont {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}
.row {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  align-self: top;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;  
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
<div class="item">
  <h2>Item 1</h2>
  <p>Here is short text</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h2>Item 2</h2>
  <p>Here is short text</p>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="item">
 <h2>Item 3</h2>
  <p>Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. </p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But what I need is this:

[image]

I don't want to set the height in pixels as my text is dynamic and the layout is responsive (the 500px width Ive set in my code is just to demonstrate the issue).

I could measure the heights with JavaScript and set a min-height that way but its hacky, is there a CSS solution?

UPDATE - My code example is simplified. In reality I will have a large number of items which need to be sorted "right" or "left". The items and which column they need to be in is dynamic.

Comment: are you allowed to change HTML structure ?

Comment: @Evans you just want 2 item in the first column or it will more?

Comment: It will be many more.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes I think that should be OK

Comment: Are ALL the items required to to be the same height or just the ones on each "row". If they are all supposed to be the same height *you need javascript*. If not then this IS possible I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **ALL** the items are required to be the same height, *you will need javascript* as there is no CSS method to equalise heights as you require.

However, if the **"rows"** are required to have items that equalise then this is possible using CSS Grid and `grid-auto-flow:column`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.left {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right {
  background: orange;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.small {
  min-height: 32px;
}

.medium {
  min-height: 60px;
}

.large {
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item left small">L1</div>
  <div class="item left medium">L2</div>
  <div class="item right large">R1</div>
  <div class="item left large">L3</div>
  <div class="item right small">R2</div>
  <div class="item right medium">R3</div>
  <div class="item left small">L4</div>
</div>
```

Note that irrepective of the min-heights (which is there for demo purposes only) the items in each "row" are maximised to the height of the tallest item.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to change html, you can use flex by making all the element in the same row and use wrap. Then you may control position using `order` property like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 1</h2>
      <p>Here is short text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 2</h2>
      <p>Here is short text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 3</h2>
      <p>Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code example is simplified. In reality I will have a large number of items which need to be sorted "right" or "left". The items and which column they need to be in is dynamic.

Comment: @Evans ok i see, but you can generate your code using the order property as inline, no ? like that you keep the CSS and structure and you change order dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
html,body{
        width:100%;
}
.cont {
    width: 500px;
     display: table;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border:1px solid blue;
       border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
        display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:10px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
.item:nth-child(even){
   border:1px solid blue;
   border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
.item:nth-child(odd){
   border:1px solid blue;
   border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Item 1</h2>
          <p>Here is short text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
         <h2>Item 2</h2>
          <p>Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text.  Here is Longer text.WW</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Item 3</h2>
          <p>Here is short text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Item 4</h2>
          <p>Here is short text</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Item 5</h2>
          <p>Here is short text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Item 6</h2>
          <p>Here is short text</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
         <h2>Item 7</h2>
          <p>Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text. Here i . Here is Longer text. Here is Longer text.  Here is Longer text.WW</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h2>Item 8</h2>
          <p>Here is short text</p>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```